# I am able to add one field to the SQLAlchemy database but gives "Operational Error" upon adding another field

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I am trying to create simple database to accept Name and Feedback from the user using SQLAlchemy and Flask. The website works fine if I only have 'feedback' in my db_models.py file. However, if I add the 'name' field, the error occurs. I have no idea what is going on as I haven't worked with Databases before. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my **init**.py file-

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'anjh23op94q2pm5h'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from vedicm import routes
```

<---->

Here is routes.py

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from vedicm import app, db
from vedicm.forms import FeedbackForm
from vedicm.db_models import FB


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def home():
    form = FeedbackForm()    #A wt form in Flask
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        fb = FB(feedback = form.feedback.data, name = form.name.data) 
        db.session.add(fb)
        db.session.commit()  #Here, all the problem occurs
        flash(f'Feedback Submitted', 'success')
    return render_template("home.html", form=form, title = 'Vedic Mishra')

@app.route("/feedbacks", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def feedbacks():
    fbs = FB.query.all()
    return render_template("feedbacks.html", title='Feedbacks', feedbacks = fbs)
```

<---->

Here is forms.py

```
from vedicm import db

class FB(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    feedback = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(25))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"FB('{self.feedback}', '{self.name}')"
```

<---->

I run this app by run.py, I get the following error.

```
**sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError**

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table FB has no column named name
[SQL: INSERT INTO "FB" (feedback, name) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('Vedic', 'Vedic')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database and the python program are 2 different things. Your program is accessing the database (that's the sqlite:///site.db). But your program thinks the table FB has the colunms id, feedback, name, while in reality it only has the columns id, feedback.

You must have created the database somehow, probably you did something like this in a python interpreter:

```
from vedicm import db
db.create_all()
```

That created your database in the file site.db. Later you made changes into your model (class FB) but your database did not update. Does it make sense?

What now? The easiest solution is probably deleting site.db and doing db.create_all() again. But you will lose the data you made so far. Another possibility would be to connect to the database file using an external tool and update it there. But as you know nothing about databases, I guess, that would be too difficult.

Finally, when you get a bit more familiar with the stuff, you should definitely look into database migrations, there is a very good tool for sqlalchemy called alembic.